# Add individual fields to delete-log-trigger when deleting PostGis-Objects via QGis

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, trigger

I am using a PostGres Database with PostGis extension (on Windows). QGis serves as a client to access (visualize and edit) certain database-tables.

I need to create a delete-log-table that saves all the information about objects I delete from a certain database-table (via QGis). So far this is easy to realize since I can use Trigger-functions in order to fill this log-table. But how can I add individual (user defined) information about every single deletion?

Is it possible to let QGis and Postgres interact in the way that some kind of "form" pops up in QGis each time I delete an object and asks the user to enter certain values (e.g. "reason_for_deletion") and then also saves these columns/values into the delete-log?

So far I haven't produced any code. I just need to know if this is possible and some basic ideas of how to realize it. 
Later I can provide code!